# Password in a URI is DEPRECATED when passing credentials to VLC

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, vlc

For a WPF app, I'm launching VLC 3.0.3 using the following code,

```
var args = "http://username:password@someurl.com --no-osd --fullscreen --no-audio --loop --volume=0";
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VlcPath"] + @"\vlc.exe";
_handle = Process.Start(path, args);
```

However, VLC still pops up with the credentials dialog, and has the username filled in. The Messages windows shows this error,

> Password in a URI is DEPRECATED

In [this Github issue](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement/issues/45), someone asks about passing the credentials via capturing the dialog event: " try to use the ShowLoginDialog event (this event should be called if credentials are needed). You can subscribe to this event, and set the username and password in the DialogResult property of the event args"

They provide this line of code:

```
e.DialogResult = new LoginDialogResult() { Username = username, Password = password };
```

If I'm using `Process.Start` to launch VLC, where does the above line go?

Comment: You can't do that if you're calling `Process.Start`, you probably need to use some sort of VLC API/SDK.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG. Any suggestions on the API/SDK?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/), you can pass them in using `--rtsp-user=<string>` and `--rtsp-pwd=<string>`. There are other options (e.g. `--sftp-user=<string>`) but I don't know which ones you actually need.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, tried those earlier. This isn't an RTSP stream, though. It's HTTP and the cameras don't have an RTSP option.

Comment: Sure - I just went with RTSP cos it was in the link you referenced. I'm just looking through the VLC source code and it doesn't look like you can pass it in at all... [Here's](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/access/http.c#L267) where it opens the stream and tries to obtain credentials and [here's](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/src/misc/keystore.c#L406) where it goes through the possible locations for the credentials, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @KirkLarkin. Yeah, it looks like I have to somehow hook into the spawned process. Not a clue how to do that.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to be pretty.